# Sort the data to plot a circle

Tags: sort, numeric-data, gnuplot, plotting

Here I have a [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3athdxjc48659oc/Sphere_ISOTEST_data.txt?dl=0) which I would to plot with line using Gnuplot.
Using the code

```
pl 'Sphere_ISOTEST_data.txt' w p
```

I get below figure

[image: this]

but, using

```
pl 'Sphere_ISOTEST_data.txt' w l
```

I get the following:

[image]

Can anyone suggest as to how to sort the data such that I can plot `w l` and get only the circumference of the circle.

Comment: And to complete the circle with @steeldriver's sorting, add the first point to the end of the data, e.g. filter the output of `sort` through `sed`: `sed '1h; $G'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be solved by [converting the Cartesian coordinates into polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) and sorting by the angle.

We can compute the angle as `atan2(y,x)`.

We may sort the original data using this computed number by applying a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) where the angle is used as the temporary sorting key:

```bsh
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print atan2($2,$1), $0 }' Sphere_ISOTEST_data.txt |
LC_ALL=C sort -g | cut -f 2-  >sorted.txt
```

The `awk` program computes the `atan2()` value from the values in the file and prepends the original lines with this value for each line, using a tab character as delimiter.  The `sort` utility then sorts the data and `cut` is used to remove the temporary sorting key.

Note that I'm using `sort -g`, which is non-standard.  The `-g` option, when implemented, usually enables a "general numeric sort", which we will need to use as some of the `atan2()` values will be in scientific notation due to being very small. We also need to use the POSIX locale ("`C`") for `sort` to read and sort the numbers correctly.  We could obviously work around this by modifying the output format of the `atan2()` values as we print them, but this at least shows the general idea.

The result is written to `sorted.txt`.

[image: Resulting plot]

```
GNUTERM=png gnuplot -e 'set size square; pl "sorted.txt" w l' >sorted.png
```