# Filter the data to generate the outermost points only

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I have the following [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zpwn72vku1nlib/Sphere_ISOA03_data.txt?dl=0), when plotted gives me the following [image]

I would like to save and plot only the outermost points with a line plot. Pls do suugest on how to proceed with this and advise on how to filter the data

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suppose the solution would be similar to the solution to your [recent question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647274/sort-the-data-to-plot-a-circle), i.e. convert into polar coordinates and work with the angle and radius. Some form of grouping by angle, and then taking the maximum radius of each group. Did you try that?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, as the radius vaires, points are ommited using a fixed radius value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive approach that, just like [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647274/sort-the-data-to-plot-a-circle) to you previous question,  [converts the Cartesian coordinates into polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates), but then groups the points based on the angle and finds the point within each group with the largest radius:

```bsh
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    {
        t = int(atan2($2,$1)*10)
        r = sqrt($1*$1+$2*$2)
    }

    r > maxr[t] { maxr[t] = r; data[t] = $0 }

    END { for (t in maxr) print t, data[t] }' data.in |
sort -k 1,1g | cut -f 2- >data.out
```

This calculates the angle with `atan2()`, then multiplies it by 10 and truncates the decimal places, yielding a value, `t`,  between -30 and 31.  This `t` is used as the grouping value, and the `maxr` array holds the maximum `r` (radius) for each such angle group (and the `data` array holds the corresponding original input data).

Multiplying the angle by a smaller number than 10 and truncating the decimals yields "bigger groups" and fewer distinct points in the end.  Multiplying with a larger value subdivides the groups further, but will eventually result in a jagged line plot (a value of 20 doesn't really work, for example).

The maximum radii values are sorted by their angle group value in a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), as in the previous answer, and the sorting key is removed with `cut` at the end.

Plotting the result:

[image]

Suggestions for improvement: The grouping of the points in *very basic* and you may want to do this a bit more carefully.  Discussing how to do that falls within the realm of https://math.stackexchange.com/